# Matlab - ode15s "Too many Input Arguments"

Tags: matlab, ode

I am trying to create a program to solve a moment methods for a polymer reaction. However, when im run the code this error appears "Too many Input Arguments", any help? (sorry for bad english)

Code:

First function

```
function dydt = osc(t,y)


ka1 = 10^6;
ka2 = 0.15*10^6;
kp = 2952;
kd = 0.106*2952;
ks = 10^6;


%y=[C,A,ROH,I,M,Lambda,Mi] <=> y(1,:)=[C]   ;  y(2,:)=[A]
%                              y(3,:)=[ROH] ;  y(4,:)=[I]
%                              y(5,:)=[M]   ;  
%                              y(6-8,:)=[Lambda] onde: %y(6) - lambda0 ; 
                                        y(7) - lambda1 ; y(8) - lambda2
%                              y(9-11,:)=[Mi] onde: %y(9) - mi0 ; y(10) - 
                                        mi1 ; y(11) - mi2
%                              y(12,:)=[R1] ; y(13;:) = [D1]


j = 10; 
syms n


%Variables
dydt(1,1) = - ka1*y(1)*y(3) + ka2*y(4)*y(2) - ka1*y(1)
dydt(2,1) = + ka1*y(1)*y(3) - ka2*y(4)*y(2) + ka1*y(1)
dydt(3,1) = - ka1*y(1)*y(3) + ka2*y(4)*y(2) - ks*y(3)*
dydt(4,1) = - kp*y(5)*y(4) + kd*y(12) + ka1*y(1)*y(3) - ka2*y(4)*y(2) 
%Living Chains
dydt(6,1) = + ka1*y(1)*symsum((n^0)*y(9), n, [1 j]) 
dydt(7,1) = + ka1*y(1)*symsum((n^1)*y(10), n, [1 j]) 
dydt(8,1) = + ka1*y(1)*symsum((n^2)*y(11), n, [1 j])
%Dormant Chains
dydt(9,1) = - ka1*y(1)*symsum((n^0)*y(9), n, [1 j]) 
dydt(10,1) = - ka1*y(1)*symsum((n^1)*y(10), n, [1 j]) + 
dydt(11,1) = - ka1*y(1)*symsum((n^2)*y(11), n, [1 j]) 
%R1 e D1
dydt(12,1) = + kp*y(5)*y(4) - kp*y(5)*y(12) + kd*((y(12)+1) - y(12))
dydt(13,1) = - ka1*y(1)*y(13) + ka2*y(2)*y(13) + ks*y(3)*y(12)

end
```

Second function

```
function [t,y]= call_osc()

%Tempo
tspan = [0 1];

%Initial conditions

C = 2.582;
A = 3.9*10^3;
ROH = 0.387*10^2;
I = 10^3;
M = 1460.495;
Rn0 = 0;
Rn1 = 0;
Rn2 = 0;
Dn0 = 0;
Dn1 = 0;
Dn2 = 0;
R1 = 1;
D1 = 1;

y0 = [C; A; ROH; I; M; Rn0; Rn1; Rn2; Dn0; Dn1; Dn2; R1; D1];

[t,y] = ode15s(@osc, tspan, y0);
disp(y(:,1))

end
```

Comment: Please check your error message, it should mention the line at which the error occurs (and the stack trace). Using the matlab debugger may help you to fix your problem.

Comment: There are [218 results on Stack Overflow alone for "too many input arguments" on the Matlab tag](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=too+many+input+arguments+%5Bmatlab%5D). Please do some research. It's likely you're calling `call_osc` from the command window and passing arguments to it

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info: The line is 29 - for the:
[t,y] = ode15s(@osc, tspan, y0);